# Update flot chart with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Hi I have two scripts and want to make one of them. I get the value of the slider into the chart but if I use the slider the chart don't make changes. I tried different  plot.draw(); but I don't find an working solution.

What I must do? Can you help me please?

```
$(function () {

    /*--------------------------------------------------
    Plugin: Slider
    --------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Increment Slider */
    $( "#incrementSlider" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value:1500,
        min: 0,
        max: 10000,
        step: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#incrementAmount" ).text ("TXT: " +  ui.value + "€");

        }
    });

    $( "#incrementAmount" ).text ( "TXT: " + $( "#incrementSlider" ).slider( "value" ) + "€" );


    var ds = [];
    var data = [];

    ds.push ([[1,$( "#incrementSlider" ).slider( "value" )]]);
    ds.push ([[1,$( "#incrementSlider" ).slider( "value" ) - $( "#incrementSlider" ).slider( "value" ) / 100 * 19,5]]);
    ds.push ([[1,$( "#incrementSlider" ).slider( "value" ) / 100 * 19,5]]);

    data.push ({
        data: ds[0], 
        label: 'Graph1', 
        bars: {
        barWidth: 0.15, 
            order: 1
        }
    });
    data.push   ({
        data: ds[1], 
        label: 'Graph2', 
        bars: {
        barWidth: 0.15, 
            order: 2
        }
    });
    data.push ({
        data: ds[2], 
        label: 'Graph3', 
        bars: {
        barWidth: 0.15, 
            order: 3
        }
    });

    Charts.vertical ('#vertical-chart', data);


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plot.draw() wont reset the data or scale the axis, it would be easier to just re-plot the whole graph (performance-wise you wont notice the difference)